# Best way (protocal) to transfer openCV webcam frame (image) to server and render the processed frame

Tags: opencv, image-processing, transfer

I want to use my laptop's webcam to fetch frames, but my device is not strong enough to handle the processing works that I suppose to do. Therefore, I want to let the server do the processing works and send the processed frame back to my laptop and render it on the window.

[image]

I am going to use Python OpenCV to fetch and render the frames on my laptop. Which protocol or implementation is best to solve the frame transfer problem in my case?

Comment: Video streaming is designed for transferring images to a remote place, but it typically uses lossy encoding like H264. If you want/need to process lossless images (which can be slow if you dont have an awesome bandwidth to your server) you can use any RPC technique. For example, apache thrift is very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to answer you definitively as it depends on your environment - hardware, software, GPU, network. The answer might be ZeroMQ, or sockets, or Redis or something else altogether.

The short answer is that you must measure/benchmark everything for yourself.

- if your network is really slow, you will do better to spend more time chroma-subsampling or compressing your data before transmitting - e.g. JPEG/MJPEG encode then send
- if your processing requires high bit-depth data, you won't be able to chroma-subsample and you may need to look at multi-processing or multi-threading or offloading to a GPU such as Videocore on Raspberry Pi.